# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String

Tags: java, php, android

I've been working out an android application with login connected to a local database. The code works perfectly fine when I input values which can be found in the table. However, when I'm trying some random inputs, it produces an error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

I've searched many times but I cant figured how to solve this problem. Please help me.

config.inc.php

```
$username ="root";
$password ="";
$dbname = "sample";
$host="localhost";



$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');



try
{

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);

}
catch(PDOException $e)

{
 die("Failed to connect to the database:" . $e->getMessage());

}
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_prc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{

    function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
    {

            foreach ($array as &$value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {

                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);

                }

                else
                {

                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
            }
    }
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);


}

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

session_start();

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff

require 'config.inc.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {

//gets user's info based off of a username.

    $query = "

        SELECT

            id,

            username,

            password

        FROM users

        WHERE

            username = :username

    ";



$query_params = array(

    ':username' => $_POST['username']

);



try {

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);

    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

}

catch (PDOException $e) {

    // For testing, you could use a die and message.

    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());



    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:

    $response["success"] = 0;

    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";

    die(json_encode($response));



}


//This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.

//we initialize it as false.

$validated_info = false;


//fetching all the rows from the query

$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row) {

    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just

    //compare the two passwords

    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {

        $login_ok = true;

    }

}



// If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page

// Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again

if ($login_ok) {

    $response["success"] = 1;

    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";

    die(json_encode($response));

} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;

    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";

    die(json_encode($response));

}

} else {


?>

    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form action="login.php" method="post">

        Username:

        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" />



        Password:

        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" />



        <input type="submit" value="Login" />

    </form>

<?php

}
 ?>
```

login.java

```
package com.example.piasi_pc1.phrism;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

   EditText et_username, et_password;
    Button btnlogin;
    ImageView pass_visible;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String LOGIN_URL =
"http://192.90.100.205/webservice_phrism/login.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    pass_visible = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_visible);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    });

    pass_visible.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = et_username.getText().toString();
        String password = et_password.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.piasi_pc1.phrism;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer already.

if ($row) {

```
//if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just

//compare the two passwords

if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {

    $login_ok = true;

}else
 {$login_ok = false;  <------missing value
 }
```

}